# Why does the load resistance has to be >100*Source resistance in case of a stiff voltage and <0.01*Source resistance in case of a stiff current?

Tags: resistance

I am using Albert Malvino's Electronic Principles and while i understand the equations to find load resistance the book does not explains the fundamental reasoning behind it.

Can anyone do better?

Comment: Are you asking about the factor 100 (that is totally arbitrary, but must be >> 1) or why a voltage source must have a low source (series) resistance and a current source a high source (parallel) ristance? (That can be shown by reasoning.)

Comment: Yes i am asking the second one. < }

Answer (score 3):

The question is asking why we need a large ratio between source resistance and load resistance.

There are two cases to consider. We could have a low impedance voltage source (ideally a zero impedance voltage source) driving a high impedance (ideally open circuit) load.  We could have a high impedance current source (ideally infinite impedance) driving a low impedance (ideally short circuit) load.

The ratios suggested in the OP's book are for at least 100:1.

It doesn't **have** to be those ratios.

But if it is, the error due to loading compared to an open circuit (for a voltage source) or a short circuit (for a current source) will be 1% or less.

If the ratios are 0.001, then the error be less than 0.1%.

If the ratios are 0.1, the error could be up to 10%.

I guess most people think 1% is somewhere in the ballpark of a negligible error. If you have different error thresholds, then you'll want to use different ratios.

Comment: I did not know how to write edit summary. but you wrote something wrong.

Comment: It is open circuit for a current source and short circuir foe a voltage source.

Comment: @user90492 each circuit consists of a high and a low, I've added another paragraph or two to clarify what I meant. I wrote the answer from the perspective of the OP's title, which was the load being driven, not the source doing the driving

Answer (score 3):

Consider the schematic below, where a voltage source \$V_S\$ with series resistance \$R_S\$ is connected to a load \$R_L\$

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f926PF.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Now the voltage across load \$V_L\$ is given by:

$$V_L = \frac{R_L}{R_S+R_L}\times V_S$$

For this voltage transfer from source to load to be high: \$R_L >> R_S\$. In other words,

$$V_L \rightarrow V_S\ \ \text{as}\ \ \frac{R_S}{R_L}\rightarrow 0$$

If \$R_L = 100R_S\$ then \$V_L = 0.990V_S\$. So this condition corresponds to an error of only 1%. If you increase this to \$R_L = 1000R_S\$ the error will only be 0.1%.(the ideal case for load is \$R_L = \infty\$, open circuit)

Similarly, for a current source,

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fn9Ije.png)</sup>

$$I_L = \frac{R_S}{R_S+R_L}$$ and 
$$I_L \rightarrow I_S\ \ \text{as}\ \ \frac{R_L}{R_S}\rightarrow 0$$

So, \$R_L = 0.01R_S\$ will correspond to 1% error.(the ideal case is \$R_L = 0\$, short circuit)